# getting hidden Django field with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django

In my form I have a hidden FloatField:

```
test         = forms.FloatField( widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

Django generates the following html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="test_set-0-test" id="id_test_set-0-test" />
```

I want to silently fill this field with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('id_test_set-0-test').value = X
```

But I do not know if Django will always generate the same id "id_test_set-0-test"?

Is there a better way for finding in JavaScript Django element by id?

Or maybe its possible to enforce id in Django backend?

Thans!

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set the ID attribute for the hidden field. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs)

```
test = forms.FloatField( widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'id':'some-custom-test-id'}))
```

Of course this only works when there is one instance of this form on the page.  You could also manually set a class attribute through this method then select all the hidden fields and do with them as your please.

Answer (score 0):

Django always generate the same id don't worry about it

and i think this is only the better way i know only jquery i would love to get value like

```
 $('#id_test_set-0-test').val();
```

the way that you are doing is right

Answer (score 0):

If this field is part of a form that's in a formset and you're using the standard Django way of rendering the formset, then yes, Django will automatically control the ID.

There are other ways to access this element other than `id`. You can select the element by css class, or by it's position in the DOM, a combination of those properties or other properties on the element like `data-[your-property-here]`

If the ID property is dynamic, in the case of a formset, I would select the element by it's position in the dom.